# Concatenate object values into one value

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

Given an array with one object

```
[
   {
      "key1":"john",
      "key2":"smith",
      "key3":"mark"
   }
]
```

I need to concatenate the values of this object into one value and get the below result with spacing between them

> john smith mark

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [ { "key1":"john", "key2":"smith", "key3":"mark" } ];

console.log(Object.values(data[0]).join(" "))
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
const givenArray = [ { "key1":"john", "key2":"smith", "key3":"mark" } ];

function processArray(arr) {
  const obj = arr[0];
  const objValues = Object.values(obj);
  return objValues.join(" ");
}

console.log(
  processArray(givenArray)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the [values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) of the object and then use a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
Object.values(a[0]).reduce((prev,acc) => `${prev} ${acc}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` that returns an array of all the Object's values: `['john', 'smith', 'mark']` and then use the `Array.protype.join` method to turn the array into a string:

```
Object.values(obj).join(' ');
```